# Angularjs addclass?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to convert this to jQuery.... Please help:

```
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.container').addClass('active');
});

$('.close').on('click', function() {
  $('.container').removeClass('active');
});
```

Here is my index.html..:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card">
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" id="Username" required="required"/>
        <label for="Username">Username</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="password" id="Password" required="required"/>
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <button><span>Go</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="footer"><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="card alt">
    <div class="toggle" ng-click="enabled=true"></div>
    <h1 class="title">Register
      <div class="close"></div>
    </h1>
    <form>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" id="Username" required="required"/>
        <label for="Username">Username</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="password" id="Password" required="required"/>
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="password" id="Repeat Password" required="required"/>
        <label for="Repeat Password">Repeat Password</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <button><span>Next</span></button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the ng-class but didnt seem to work... I dont understand how to convert the jQuery code above to angular. Help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple demo with `ng-click` and `ng-class` directives of Angular: http://plnkr.co/edit/JJXs5BPB2e5owIYReFxO?p=preview

Html in your template:

```
<div ng-controller="showcaseCtrl">
  <button ng-click="doStuff()">doStuff</button>
  <div class="container" ng-class="{'active': isActive}">this is container</div>
</div>
```

JS in controller

```
 $scope.doStuff = function(){
   $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
 }
```

There is no need in `.toggle` class on the element that triggers the event. What it does is call `doStuff` function in the controller. That function toggles the value of the `isActive` scope variable.
And that variable change is read by `ng-class` directive on the `.content` block - and if it's true class `active` is added;

Comment: You have no app initialisation, no controller. of course thta won't work. Man you should start from reading what angular is and how it works, and what are the parts needed, monkey patching not always works

Comment: this version also has jQuery in it. If you want help at least use solutions that are provided to you and match the code in the question

Comment: I didn't get your point @charlietfl There's no jQuery in that example I am referencing.

Comment: @shershen i meant the demo provided by OP is still using jQuery on top of your code. Wasn't meant to say anything about your solution. frustrated when someone says something doesn't work and then shows their old demo without implementing new solutions

Comment: I did it thanks for your help. I was just furstrated. sorry

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have variable `enabled` being toggled all you need is:

```
<div class="container" ng-class="{active: enabled}">
```

then also toggle same variable in `close` element

Comment: Im confused what about js?

Comment: create a demo then, no reason it shouldn't unless you have child scopes involved that are not shown

Comment: Yea can you fork it and try to make that work in angular?

Comment: where's the version you tried? It was your claim that it doesn't work

Comment: that codepen doesn't match the code in question even. your toggle class `ng-click is calling a function, not enabled=true

Comment: Yes it dosent because i edited it back... Why are you so concerned of mathing?

Comment: matching i meant.. Now i edited it back to my previous one.. as you can see: http://codepen.io/amanuel2/pen/bEPdew?editors=1010

Comment: well if you did it, you did it with the help of one of these answers ...shouldn't you accept one of them?